# Update MySQL data from HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm a beginner in HTML, PHP, JavaScript and MySQL. I've written a HTML code to enter data into a simple table containing columns "Name" and "Email" in MySQL by employing a seperate PHP file. Then I tried fetching the table contents using PHP. But now I need a little help in updating the data. My code is as follows:

```
enter code here<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="javascript" src="update.js"></script>
<?php
    $a=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test4");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($a,"select * FROM test");    
?>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding"1">
    <tr>
            <th>pkid</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++)
        {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>      
        <tr>
            <td id="pkid"><?php echo $row['pkid'] ?></td>
            <td id="name"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td id="email"><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
            <td><input type=submit onclick="myfunc()" value="View"/></td>
        </tr>
<?php   
        } 
?>
    </table>

    <form action="insert.php" method="post">

            <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Add">

            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
</html>
<?php 
    mysqli_close($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code for Update Data to MYSQL :

Html File :

```
<title>Listing Details for Update</title>
<?php
include ('config.php');
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>pkid</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email-Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Action</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['pkid']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
 <td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Here you can find the way for Update Single Field, Multiple Field Etc.,

http://php.sysaxiom.com/update_data.php

http://php.sysaxiom.com/update_multiple_data.php

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the contents of the table to have different rows/row data, (and you want to do it live) you will need to use AJAX.  jQuery has fairly straightforward ajax usage, so for actual implementation, I would look to that.  You'll also need another PHP file that just returns the raw HTML required to fill in the table.  Pseudocode (jquery) below:

```
$.post("url","dataToPost",function(data){$("#table id where I want to put new data).innerHTML=data});
```

Basically, the `$.post()` posts the `dataToPost` to the `url` and sets the `innerHTML` of whatever you select to the resultant `data`.